# Downloading instead of executing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp, download

We have legacy IBM registers which use a very old browser called "ICE".  It has a receipt printer attached and running.

We have new Windows XP registers which have Internet Explorer 8.  It has a receipt printer attached and running.jsp - d

I have a Windows XP machine which has Internet Explorer 8.  It has a network printer available and running.

---

We have a HTML page with some javascript

```
document.form1.target = 'frameProcess';
document.form1.action = (jspFolder + 'TransferPrintOutput.jsp');
document.form1.submit();
```

---

This .jsp file does a ton of *response.getWriter().println(...)* statements.

When the HTML page is loaded on the ICE browser (from legacy IBM register), the .jsp page runs as expected, and the output is sent to the printer.

When the HTML page is loaded on the Windows register, or my Windows PC, the browser comes up with the Open / Save / Cancel dialog.

The JSP page is in a "Tomcat" directory on the server, and I've been reading about a lot of issues with Tomcat hosting JSP's to a windows client.

How do i make the JSP run, rather than download?

---

I've just read [in one spot](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/64219/how-to-execute-jsp-file) that it is required to have Tomcat running on the client, which would cause this issue i think, but find that hard to believe.

Comment: I would recommend enabling access.log on Tomcat to monitor what URLs are being accessed in both cases and compare them. JSP is compiled into servlet. Tomcat uses JspServlet servlet, which is mapped as *.jsp, to invoke JSP-page. Here's some info on how to enable access.log: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/AccessLogValve

Comment: I would gladly do that, but unfortunately I can't make changes to Tomcat or the settings.  We do not have a "test" version, and it is heavily used in a production environment.